# ogr2ogr bringing up "memory allocation error"

Tags: sql-server, ogr2ogr, osgeo4w

I've got a shapefile which contains, at the moment, roughly 1500 polygons. The polygons all display fine using whatever GIS I throw it in (ArcGIS, QGIS).

However, I'm trying to use ogr2ogr to convert it to a table on SQL Server and it gives the following error:

> ERROR 1: INSERT command for new feature failed. [Microsoft][SQL Server
>   Native Client 11.0]Memory allocation failure ERROR 1: Unable to write
>   feature 8 from layer PARCEL_MP. ERROR 1: Terminating translation
>   prematurely after failed translation of layer PARCEL_MP (use
>   -skipfailures to skip errors)

Of course, I can use `-skipfailures` but when I do, it manages to export roughly 120 of the 1500 records (it differs each time - sometimes it's 115, sometimes 120, a bit more or less).

Obviously what I'm shooting for is 100%. The server is SQL Server 2014.

My code (running this in OSGeo4W) is:

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=MY_SERVER;database=MY_DATABASE;trusted_connection=yes" "PARCEL_MP.shp"
```

EDIT - also, the first feature that throws an error changes each time. The shapes aren't complicated and are quite small, with a small number of vertices.

Also, just tried using ogr2ogr to convert it to another shapefile which has worked fine. Think it must be in my server. Code I used was:

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -f "ESRI Shapefile" "PARCEL_MP_2.shp" "PARCEL_MP.shp" -skipfailures
```

Comment: I just wanted to add to this that I too am experiencing the exact same problem. I know that doesn't help you, but it does show that it isn't an isolated issue. The shp file I'm using had worked previously with the ogr2ogr command. I will be filing a ticket w the GDAL folks.

Comment: I too am having this issue. I'm going from a WFS point feature into SQLExpress.

_italic_ **bold** ogr2ogr -skipfailures -overwrite -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;database=Import;trusted_connection=yes" wfs:"https://xxx.com.au/gis/?key=xxxx&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION-1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=xxxx:wfs_BBQ" 

Versions:sql server 13.0.4001 and OSgoe4W shell version that comes with QGIS 2.18.3 (GDAL 2.1.2, released 2016/10/24)

Comment: I was having the same problems and just had success using `-lco UPLOAD_GEOM_FORMAT=wkt`

Comment: Is it solved now? what did you do to make it work? downgrading to previous versions?

Comment: Suggestion by @chris also works for me: ogr2ogr -lco UPLOAD_GEOM_FORMAT=wkt -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=XXXXX;database=YYYYY;trusted_connection=yes" "ZZZZZ.geojson"

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem, I used Chirs's solution and worked for me -

```
    ogr2ogr -f MSSQLSpatial -overwrite  -lco UPLOAD_GEOM_FORMAT=wkt "MSSQL:server=XXXXXXX;database=XXXXXX;trusted_connection=yes" -nln "XXXXX" "XXXX.Shp"
```

I just used "-lco UPLOAD_GEOM_FORMAT=wkt"

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 2):

As @Calanus and @jburn mention, this appears to be a bug ([#6589](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6589)).

> ogr2ogr appears to fail when trying to convert to MSSQL Spatial. I
>   have some shp files that I have uploaded previously to SQL Server with
>   a pre 2.0 build and it worked fine. After upgrading to 2.1 I get an
>   error about the native drive having a memory allocation issue. Nothing
>   has changed on my system though and as mentioned, it worked previously
>   with these same files. I have attempted to use the "Driver" variable
>   to specify using just "SQL Server" driver as opposed to the "Native
>   11" version, but I still get an error.

I get the same issue importing a WFS point feature.

Comment: Wish that ogr2ogr folks would look into this issue....

Comment: I agree! I left a comment on the ticket but that did raise any attention. I'm not sure how else to highlight the issue to the org2ogr people!

Comment: What does he mean by **pre 2.0 build**? I downloaded version 1.3.0.3 from http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/windows/ and it does not have ogr2ogr.exe file.

Comment: I had success by installing an old version of QGIS (2.10) with ogr2ogr as part of the install. This worked for me. I checked the GDAL ticket and there appears to be no activity against it so I do not think it has been fixed yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a bug in the recent versions of ogr2ogr as installing a pre-version 2 version imported a 3gb shapefile with no issues

Comment: Still failing with GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01

Comment: Installed http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1800-x64-gdal-2-1-mapserver-7-0/gdal-201-1800-x64-core.msi and problem was resolved.  It reported a warning which might relate to the failure:

`Warning 1: Failed to get extent for spatial index.`

Answer (score 0):

you likely need to repair the geometry of at least one the polygons. You can view them if you have illegal geometry but not convert to a table if you have polygon geo issues.

In ArcGIS use [repair geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/repair-geometry.htm).

In Grass use [v.clean](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.clean.html)

Comment: Just tried that and still having issues. Looking into whether I'm doing it right.

Comment: Nope, still not working. Apparently there are no geometry problems.

Comment: do me a favor. bring it into a file geodatabase feature class and then back to a shapefile. and then try the new shapefile. Something it up with feature 8. so you can just remove this one as well (probably id 7 if it starts at 0) and just do the rest.

Comment: Still the same issue. And unfortunately I can't afford to remove features, and it changes each time (sometimes it's 8, sometimes 10, sometimes 2). If I use `-skipfailures` it brings up over 1000 failures in a shapefile of only 1500.

Comment: Just added a bit more info - confident that it's not a problem with the shapefile as a shapefile to shapefile has just worked fine.